# angular-cli simple configuration without test and ng serve

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, angular-cli

I have java webapp with `angular2` support.

packaging and compilation of .java and .ts files is done through maven, then we run .war using spring-boot that gives hot deployment of code.

I want to use `angular-cli` only up to a consent, for generating components, services, etc.. i don't have plan to add jasmine tests yet so i am not worried about testing, server configuration etc.. i do not want webpacking and  additional `angular-cli` garbage files either. only what is already defined in `package.json`
is there a way i can use angular-cli on existing project for generating file structure only ?

Following are project and file structure.

```
src/main/webapp
src/main/webapp/package.json
src/main/webapp/systemjs.config.js
src/main/webapp/app
src/main/webapp/main.ts
src/main/webapp/module.ts
src/main/webapp/component.ts
src/main/webapp/landing.html
src/main/webapp/node_modules
```

following is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "angular-simple-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple app",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
  },

}
```

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but you can use this command line to create the minimal app and without any tests:

```
ng new <project_name> --skip-test --minimal
```

Comment: Check your clip version for me it was 1.7.4 they have made changes recently

Comment: Please note that `--minimal` might have another side effects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429245/what-does-minimal-do-in-angular-cli-ng-new

Comment: Error: Unknown argument: skip-test

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the alias `st` (skip test) also `ng new <project_name> --st`, which does the same thing