# Add tests to an Angular 'minimal' CLI app

Tags: angular

I've used `ng new my-app --minimal` to scaffold an Angular 5 CLI app to play around with. After doing so for a bit, I found that I did want a spec file for something. So what I did was:

1. Create a file `/src/app/my-thing.ts` with a class
2. Create a file `/src/app/my-thing.spec.ts` with content `describe('MyThing', () => { ... }`

But obviously `describe(...)` cannot be found, because [`--minimal` skips setting up tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429245/what-does-minimal-do-in-angular-cli-ng-new), so there's nothing there to support it.

How do I properly add a tests setup that'll work nicely with `ng test`?

Comment: You'll need jasmine for sure

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thx for the reply. My first attempt was just `npm i jasmine` and go from there, but it didn't end well so after a bit I decided to do a more 'brute force' appraoch. I've shared it as an answer, but still hope someone can teach me a smarter way/trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd prefer to learn if there's a CLI-based solution for this, but for now I've just pushed on and used some git, diff, and cli magic to see what was needed to get up and running. Here's the dumb solution:

1. Update `.angular-cli.json` removing:

   ```
   "class": {
     "spec": false
   }
   ```
2. Update `.angular-cli.json` setting `"spec": false` to `true` everywhere inside `"component"`
3. Add these to `package.json`:

   ```
   "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
   "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
   "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
   "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
   "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
   "karma": "~2.0.0",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
   "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
   "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
   "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
   ```

   and run `npm install` to get those packages installed.
4. Add this (or similar) in a new file `karma.conf.js` in the project root:

   ```
   module.exports = function (config) {
     config.set({
       basePath: '',
       frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
       plugins: [
         require('karma-jasmine'),
         require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
         require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
         require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
         require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
       ],
       client:{
         clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
       },
       coverageIstanbulReporter: {
         reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
         fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
       },
       angularCli: {
         environment: 'dev'
       },
       reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
       port: 9876,
       colors: true,
       logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
       autoWatch: true,
       browsers: ['Chrome'],
       singleRun: false
     });
   };
   ```
5. Add this to a new file `src/test.ts`:

   ```
   import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
   import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
   import {
     BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
     platformBrowserDynamicTesting
   } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

   declare const require: any;

   // First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
   getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
     BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
     platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
   );
   // Then we find all the tests.
   const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
   // And load the modules.
   context.keys().map(context);
   ```
6. Add this new file `src/tsconfig.spec.json`:

   ```
   {
     "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
     "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
       "baseUrl": "./",
       "module": "commonjs",
       "types": [
         "jasmine",
         "node"
       ]
     },
     "files": [
       "test.ts"
     ],
     "include": [
       "**/*.spec.ts",
       "**/*.d.ts"
     ]
   }
   ```

Now you should be able to run `ng test` and see your tests run.

Hope this helps someone.